# In my UIViewController I want the user to select either of two options. What would be the simple ui element in xcode to implement this?

Tags: ios

I dont want to use a UITableView nor a pickerView because I just have two options to select from. How could I implement it in the simplest way. Isnt there some kind of radio option in xcode ?

Also I have a space cruch on my UIView to incorporate a PickerView!

Comment: There is no standard radio button control in UIKit. You can build one if that is what you want to use. Or use https://github.com/t4ku/RadioButtonWithUIKit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're boolean-like options, use `UISwitch`. Otherwise `UISegmentedControl` is your friend.